# how to store html.response in a variable?

Tags: javascript, geoip

I am using the function

```
 geoip2.cityISPOrg(function (response) {
 $("#country").html(response.country.names.en);
 $("#city").html(response.city.names.en);
 $("#isp").html(response.traits.isp);
 }, null, { w3cGeolocationDisabled: true });
```

i want to store the city value in a variable and alert the response later

Actually the function is stored in an external .js file which is called from the html file and the source for geoip is provided in the html file

Comment: Did you try storing the city value in a variable from outer scope?

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = response
```

Note that `foo` will remain undefined until the asynchronous function has been resolved.

You should probably declare `foo` (using `var foo` outside the call to `cityISPOrg`).

Comment: @user3706009 — It's the first argument to the anonymous function you are passing to `cityISPOrg`. If it is undefined then you are either ignoring the middle part of this answer (starting "Note") or none of the rest of the code is working already.

Comment: we are sending the response argument to pass the information to the function, but i need the output

Comment: You get the output when the function you are passing gets called by `cityISPOrg`

Answer (score 0):

You could set a global variable, which can be done a few ways, but a simple way is to just leave `var` off the declaration. Eg:

```
city = response.city.names.en;
```

Or, you can actually just grab the value from within the `#city` html element after you've put it there. This way is useful because once it's in the DOM you can grab it from any javascript file without worrying about passing the value over...

```
city = $("#city").html();
```

Comment: I tried the second part,but its not working.
I think we need to assign a var outside the function as said earlier